# Custom workflow parameters missing

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013, ilmerge

I have a custom workflow in CRM which has 2 required parameters.

We have then been recently playing around with ILMerge so that plugins and workflows can both reference to one library. So far there hasn't been any issues with plugins, however the parameters are missing when trying to call the workflow from the designer.

Does using ILMerge on CRM Custom workflows strip out the parameters or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: if you don't merge the dll the parameters appear in the designer?

Comment: @GuidoPreite the parameters go as soon as i install ILMerge

Comment: Do you merge into once assembly with BOTH plugins and activities in and just deploy the one assembly to CRM or have a separate merged assembly for each? It definitely works with just plugins in one and just activities in another, but I have never tried with both in one

Comment: @BenWilliams Before i had 3 dll's, 1 for plugins, 1 for workflows and 1 for the libraries that both needed access to but was installed on the GAC. Now I'm trying to move the 3rd dll into both plugins and workflows to then hopefully end up with 2 dlls.

Comment: That should definitely work then, that is exactly what we do (but with a whole load of assemblies common to both activities and plugins)

Comment: I had a similar issue once. Turns out that I was targeting the wrong .Net version. Needs to be 4.5.2 (I had 4.5).